# secret-inject@azurekeyvault waiting forever

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, azure-keyvault, helm3, akv2k8s

I would like to use akv2k8s.io for adding key vault into kubernetes using helm chart.

```
apiVersion: spv.no/v2beta1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: secret-sync 
  namespace: akv-test-butfa
spec:
  vault:
    name: akv2k8s-butfa # name of key vault
    object:
      name: myusername # name of the akv object
      type: secret # akv object type
  output: 
    secret: 
      name: my-secret-from-butfa # kubernetes secret name
      dataKey: secret-value # key to store object value in kubernetes secret
```

And my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: akvs-secret-app
  namespace: akv-test-butfa
  labels:
    app: akvs-secret-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: akvs-secret-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: akvs-secret-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: akv2k8s-env-test
        image: spvest/akv2k8s-env-test:2.0.1
        args: ["TEST_SECRET"]
        env:
        - name: TEST_SECRET
          value: "secret-inject@azurekeyvault" # ref to akvs
```

I have created keyvault is name: `akv2k8s-butfa` with secret and I have set permission for that.

```
$kubectl -n akv-test get akvs
    NAME          VAULT                VAULT OBJECT   SECRET NAME   SYNCHED   AGE
    secret-sync   akv2k8s-test-butfa   mysecret                               6h26m
```

But I got issuse:

```
secret-inject@azurekeyvault
waiting forever...
```

When I see logs of deployment.

Update:

```
State:          Waiting
  Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       Error
  Exit Code:    1
  Started:      Fri, 29 Oct 2021 07:50:15 +0700
  Finished:     Fri, 29 Oct 2021 07:50:15 +0700
Ready:          False
Restart Count:  7
Environment Variables from:
  my-secret-from-butfa  Secret  Optional: false
Environment:            <none>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, i also played this week with akv2k8s :)

Did you create a role assignment for the kubelet identity to your keyvault?

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "akv_k8s_reader" {
  scope                = azurerm_key_vault.akv.id
  role_definition_name = "Key Vault Secrets User"
  principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
}
```

or

```
export KUBE_ID=$(az aks show -g <resource group> -n <aks cluster name> --query identityProfile.kubeletidentity.objectId -o tsv)
export AKV_ID=$(az keyvault show -g <resource group> -n <akv name> --query id -o tsv)
az role assignment create --assignee $KUBE_ID --role "Key Vault Secrets User" --scope $AKV_ID
```

NOTE: Your Azure KeyVault needs RBAC enabled.

I also noticed that you only need this if you need the injector function:

```
apiVersion: spv.no/v2beta1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: secret-sync 
  namespace: akv-test-butfa
spec:
  vault:
    name: akv2k8s-butfa # name of key vault
    object:
      name: myusername # name of the akv object
      type: secret # akv object
```

The output in the  AzureKeyVaultSecret function is for using it as secret sync and then your pod manifest would look like this:

```
  envFrom:
  - secretRef:
      name: my-secret-from-butfa
```

Comment: Hi  @Philip Welz, How to check if it applies correctly ?

Comment: i would suggest to use to secret sync function form akv2k8s, there you also see that status of the sync. Using secrets from ENV variables is not recommended. You should mount this secret as volume.

Comment: Just updated an image on the question, It has an Environment variable there

Comment: so it is working?

Comment: do you know authService = false in injector pod? I got identity permision on keyvault